# How to change wheel scroll orientation on specific element and then return it back to normal with React or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, framer-motion

[layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSh6e.png)

[layout prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0xmy.gif)

How can I achieve that scrolling behavior in React? The user just needs to scroll the mouse wheel down and when the user reached page 2 on the screen, the logic will change the mouse scroll direction from vertical to horizontal until the X distance of page 3 is fully reached, then and only then the mouse wheel direction back to vertical. Also, it must work reversed when the user mouse scrolls up (beginning from page 3).

I've tried with useInView hooks from framer motion but the hooks can't keep up with the scrolling speed (sometimes there's a certain amount of page 1 or 3 is rendered when stopping at page 2).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.